# When adding "\n" to a Java String , the newline is not presented in a JSP but on stdin it does

Tags: java, html, jsp, web-applications, servlets

When I pass a java string back to my servlet , the servlet passes that string to the jsp .

The string holds names & addresses with a new line "\n" , but when I'm trying to present 
that on the screen , I see a full line , however on the console the new-line is presented .

Here's a snapshot : 
**First**
[image]
**Second** 
[image]
**Third : from the CONSOLE**

[image]

Any idea how to solve that ?

Regards

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In HTML, newline characters are treated like spaces, and multiple spaces are displayed as a single space. If you want to go to the next line, you must transform newline characters into `<br />`, or enclose your text inside a `<pre></pre>` block.

Comment: Can I put that in the String that (the `br`) I build before I send it to the servlet ?

Comment: You can, but it would be awful. The database access code shouldn't handle HTML-related problems. Instead of returning a String, the method should return an object or a list of objects (with a name, lastName and address fields), and the JSP should display the properties of those objects as it needs to (i.e. separated by `<br />`. Don't mix the presentation logic with the database logic, and vice-versa. That way, if you want to use tables instead of newlines, the database logic won't be modified. Only the JSP.